# Linq with join, sum and group by C#

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables given below:
Table 01: Incomes.

```
Id  |  Amount |  Date       | UserId
1   |  50000  | 2019-01-10  |   1
1   |  10000  | 2019-01-15  |   1
1   |  15000  | 2019-02-16  |   1
1   |  20000  | 2019-03-01  |   1
```

Table 02: Expenses.

```
Id  |  Amount |  Date       | UserId
1   |  10000  | 2019-03-24  |   1
1   |   5000  | 2019-03-24  |   1
1   |  30000  | 2019-04-24  |   1
1   |  20000  | 2019-05-24  |   1
```

I want to get the per month incomes and expenses together.
Actually the result I want is something like (based on the tables above):

```
Month  |  Income  |  Expenses
   01  |  60000   |     0
   02  |  15000   |     0
   03  |  20000   |   15000
   04  |    0     |   30000
   05  |    0     |   20000
```

What I have tried so far:

```
var incomes = await _context.Incomes.Where(i => i.Date.Year == year && i.UserId == id && i.IsApproved).ToListAsync();
var expenses = await _context.Expenses.Where(e => e.Date.Year == year && e.UserId == id && e.IsApproved).ToListAsync();

var yearlyIncomes = incomes.GroupBy(
            i => i.Date.Month, 
            i => i.Amount,
            (month, income) => new { Month = month, Income = income.Sum() }).OrderBy(i => i.Month).ToList();

var yearlyExpenses = expenses.GroupBy(
            e => e.Date.Month, 
            e => e.Amount,
            (month, expense) => new { Month = month, Expense = expense.Sum() }).OrderBy(e => e.Month).ToList();
```

In this way, I can get the per month income and expense individually.

I also tried:

```
var yearlyIncomes = incomes.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Month)
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Month = x.Key,
                            Income = x.Sum(p => p.Amount),
                            Expense = expenses.Where(c => x.Any(p => p.Date.Month == c.Date.Month)).Sum(c => c.Amount)
                        }).ToList();
```

Is there any way to get the desired result by one query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second query will not be efficient as it will try to get the expenses once for every month. Your first approach looks fine (sometime more is better). One thing you can do is join income and expense on the user ID and then just do group by on the month to get both income and expenses. Also your group by looks weird, you should group on month and sum the income/expense.

Comment: With asynchronous calls you don't need to make it in one query. Execute both queries "simultaneously" by calling them without awaiting. await both queries with `Task.WhenAll` then calculate required result.

Comment: @ArfizurRahman hope you can try my answer

Comment: @GabrielLlorico Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it is not working. I'm getting not my desired result. ex: If you check the example output table in my question, there is only one row for month three for both income and expense but according to your solution I'm getting two rows for month 3. i.e one for income and one for expense which should be in the same row. Thanks

Comment: @ArfizurRahman, I see, i forgot to regroup again, wait, updating my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if you dont want to group it by `UserId` you could do it in one linq but it would be long

```
var groupedIncome = incomes
                 .GroupBy(inc => inc.Date.Month) //group it by month
                 .Select(groupedIncomeByMonth => 
                     new { 
                         Month = groupedIncomeByMonth.Key, 
                         Amount = groupedIncomeByMonth
                                      .Sum(monthIncome => monthIncome.Amount), 
                         IsIncome = true}).ToList(); // Marker for Concat/Union All

var groupedExpenses = expenses
                    .GroupBy(exp => exp.Date.Month)
                    .Select(groupedExpenseByMonth => 
                        new { 
                            Month = groupedExpenseByMonth.Key, 
                            Amount = groupedExpenseByMonth
                                         .Sum(monthExpense => monthExpense.Amount), 
                            IsIncome = false }).ToList(); // marker for Concat/Union All

var result = groupedIncome.Concat(groupedExpenses)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                  .Select(r => 
                               new { 
                                       Month = r.Key, 
                                       Income = r.Where(p => p.IsIncome).Sum(g => g.Amount), 
                                       Expense = r.Where(p => !p.IsIncome).Sum(g => g.Amount)
                                   }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Tried your updared answer. Throws this exception: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object] Concat[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object], System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object])'

Comment: @ArfizurRahman hmm, i think you should execute these in memory

Comment: @GrabrielLlorico I had to change the ToListAsync() to ToList() to make it work. Thanks for your answer and cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to union all data and group them before materializing them by calling `ToListAsync()` method.

```
var incomes = _context
    .Incomes
    .Where(i => i.Date.Year == year && i.UserId == id && i.IsApproved)
    .Select(i => new { Month = i.Date.Month, Income = i.Amount, Expense = 0 });

var expenses = _context
    .Expenses
    .Where(e => e.Date.Year == year && e.UserId == id && e.IsApproved)
    .Select(e => new { Month = e.Date.Month, Income = 0, Expense = e.Amount });

var summary = await incomes
    .Concat(expenses)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Month)
    .Select(g => new { Month = g.Key, Incomes = g.Sum(x => x.Income), Expenses = g.Sum(x => x.Expense) })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Union removes duplicities (i.e. same income in the same month). The right operator should be Concat imho.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek: Oh yeah. Concat, UNION ALL! Thanks!

Comment: @dropoutcoder Thanks for the answer. Trying your solution with Concat but it throws the exception: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object] Concat[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object], System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Object])' . Failed to find any solution. Any idea?